# Combining ±% with ±dB in measurement uncertainty

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, measurement-theory

Firstly apologies if this is not the correct place to post this but wasn't sure which site would be good to ask regarding about measurement uncertainty calculation.

I am trying to calculate the combined measurement uncertainty, however the uncertainties I want to combine are using different scales:

Carrier level uncertainty: ±0.5dB (logarithmic)

Modulation uncertainty: ±5% (linear)

Converting either from one format to another will not give me a simple ±value in the other format

What is the best way to combine these uncertainties